# Preventing Multiple Animations from occurring at the same time in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, animation

I'm making a simple Simon Says style game and use a for loop to go through the array of colors that have been added. Currently every time you click the button it will add a color and run the for loop. My problem is that when two conditionals are met, instead of animating one color then the next, it animates both at the same time. I tried using setInterval which just made an infinite loop, and setTimeout just makes the first animation wait before it happens. Does anyone know how I can get each color to animate one at a time?

In my demo please scroll to the bottom of the js. The top is color.js which allows the color animation. Click the button a few times to see how the animations are behaving.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/woxopukika/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
var colors = [];
var red, yellow, blue, green;

//random number
mathF = function() {
    return Math.random();
};

//determine what color is added
function newColorF() {
    var math = mathF();
    if(math <= .25) {
        newColor = 'red';
    }
    else if(math <= .5) {
        newColor = 'green';
    }
    else if(math <= .75) {
        newColor = 'yellow';
    }
    else {
        newColor = 'blue';
    }
    return newColor;
}

function computerTurn() {
    newColor = newColorF();
    colors.push(newColor);
    var colorlength = colors.length;
    setTimeout(function() {
    for(i=0; i<colorlength; i++) {
        x = colors[i];
        console.log(x);
        if(x === 'red') {
            $('#red').animate({
                backgroundColor: '#ff9e9e'
            }, 750)
            .delay(250)
            .animate({
                backgroundColor: 'red'
            }, 750);
        }
        else if(x === 'green') {
            $('#green').animate({
                backgroundColor: '#bdffbd'
            }, 750)
            .delay(250)
            .animate({
                backgroundColor: 'green'
            }, 750);
        }
        else if(x === 'yellow') {
            $('#yellow').animate({
                backgroundColor: '#ffffc2'
            }, 750)
            .delay(250)
            .animate({
                backgroundColor: 'yellow'
            }, 750);
        }
        else {
            $('#blue').animate({
                backgroundColor: '#a3a3ff'
            }, 750)
            .delay(250)
            .animate({
                backgroundColor: 'blue'
            }, 750);
        }
    }
}, 500);
}
//when begin button is pushed
function beginGame() {
    computerTurn();
}

$('#startGame').click(function() {
    beginGame();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution to this that I can think of is to use the `complete` callback parameter of the [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function.

```
function computerTurn() {
    newColor = newColorF();
    colors.push(newColor);
    var colorlength = colors.length;

    var i = 0; // Our iteration variable

    var check = function() { // the function to increment i and go to next step of animation, or exit
        i++;
        if (i < colorlength) {
            step();
        }
    };

    var step = function() {
        x = colors[i];
        console.log(x);
        if (x === 'red') {
            $('#red').animate({
                    backgroundColor: '#ff9e9e'
                }, 750)
                .delay(250)
                .animate({
                    backgroundColor: 'red'
                }, 750, check); // <--- attached check function here
        } else if (x === 'green') {
            $('#green').animate({
                    backgroundColor: '#bdffbd'
                }, 750)
                .delay(250)
                .animate({
                    backgroundColor: 'green'
                }, 750, check); // <--- attached check function here
        } else if (x === 'yellow') {
            $('#yellow').animate({
                    backgroundColor: '#ffffc2'
                }, 750)
                .delay(250)
                .animate({
                    backgroundColor: 'yellow'
                }, 750, check); // <--- attached check function here
        } else {
            $('#blue').animate({
                    backgroundColor: '#a3a3ff'
                }, 750)
                .delay(250)
                .animate({
                    backgroundColor: 'blue'
                }, 750, check); // <--- attached check function here
        }
    };

    step(); // For the initial step in the animation
}
```

Here, what I've done is instead of using a `for` loop to iterate through the `colors` array, I have used a recursive approach via the `complete` callback which `animate` accepts as its last parameter.

---

From the documentation on `complete`:

> complete
>
> Type: Function()
>
> A function that is called once the animation on an element is complete.

---

I've broken the code into 2 functions: `step` and `check`.

`step` executes the next step of the animation.

`check` is used to check if the array is fully iterated. If it is, then exit. Otherwise, call `step`.

At the very end, I have called `step` manually to begin the animation sequence.

---

**NOTE:** There are probably better solutions out there, I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you mean to queue the animations? The animate() actually allows this with the queue property:

```
    if(x === 'red') {
        $('#red').animate({backgroundColor: '#ff9e9e'}, {
        queue: true,
        duration: 750,
        delay: 250
    });
```

Comment: Actually, I believe that the queue option defaults to true.